# I want to check HNT balance for My SOL address using JS.? Below is the code please check

Tags: solana-program, spl-token

Here I have an address but the result is showing blank...as there is no token associated with the address but I want to know and check the HNT balance if available in the address and also how can I get the HNT from faucet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please ask exactly one question at a time (feel free to open multiple questions on this site). Also, your question is missing the code example that your title suggests should have been included.